# Matching does not stop at EOL when searching in VsVim

Tags: regex, vim, vsvim

Using VS 2010 with VsVim.

I'm finding that a search for quoted text, e.g.

```
/["][^"]\{0,\}["]
```

Which is one of the several different efforts I made to find a quote, maybe some stuff excluding quotes, followed by another quote, for example `"stuff"`, or `""` (empty string), or whatever other quoted string.

This search is not necessarily confined to a single line.  I haven't yet done any exhaustive analysis to determine if there's something in common with all those multi-line matches, though an escaped quote (`\"`) seems to be fairly common.

I tried a number of restrictive additions, but it wasn't until I added `\n` to the exclusion set that it quit doing that.

In gVim, the search is, by default, confined to a single line.

I can see the advantage of having a search cross line-end boundaries, but that's not what I want as the default.

Is there a setting I missed?

Here's an example of a match from that regex:

```
        oss << "bonus game conditions \"" << index << "\" not found for bonus game \""
        << bonusGameID << "\"";
```

That's two lines of code, containing five matches.

```
"bonus game conditions \"
" << index << "
" not found for bonus game \"
```

then

```
"
        << bonusGameID << "
```

and

```
""
```

The match we're interested in is this one:

```
"
        << bonusGameID << "
```

Because that's the one that spans a line break.

---

Here's another one, with the first quote being single-quoted between apostrophes:

```
                CharReplace( *it, wchar_t( '"' ), L"<DQ>" );

            if ( !arg.empty() )
            {
                args.push_back( arg );
            }
        }

        it++;
    }

    // Re-compose the string from words
    WordsToString( words, delimiters, _str );

    // Replace newlines with ICU specifiers (NOTE: CS3 uses '\r' instead of '\n' for a newline)
    CharReplace( _str, wchar_t( '\n' ), L"<NL>" ) || CharReplace( _str, wchar_t( '\r' ), L"<NL>" );
```

The first match begins where the `'"'` is on line one up to the `L"` before `<DQ>`, and the second one picks up the `"` after the `<DQ>` and continues until the opening quote of `"<NL>"` on the last line.

What's happening isn't really a mystery.  What's puzzling is the decision to allow the match to include the line breaks by default.

---

Okay, so I did a little more experimenting. Here's what I think is happening.

It's the `[^"]` sub-expression as nearly as I can tell.  It doesn't matter what I begin the expression with, if I write `/_[^_]_/` I get similar behavior, a newline is—quite literally—"not a member of the set of only an underscore".  (Alternatively, it is implicitly a member of "everything that's not an underscore".)

In a normal search (`/_.*_/`, which does a greedy search for whatever is between two underscores), the search stays on a single line (or, more precisely, doesn't cross a newline break), because a newline not actually a member of "zero or more of anything at all".

So a newline is not a member of `.*` but it ***is*** a member of `[^_]` or `[^"]` or pick whatever you want to exclude.

To ensure the search does not cross a newline boundary, an exclusion set must explicitly include `\n` (newline).

I have confirmed that gVim implicitly excludes newlines from the "not-one-of-these" set.  In order to get gVim to include the end-of-line, one must prepend `\_` to the collection brackets, thus:  `\_[]` (or include a `\n` in the collection).

---

**Conclusion**:  If this is a "feature" in VsVim, it should be something you can turn on and off.  If it is unexpected behavior, then could it be a bug?

Comment: Okay, so bunch of edits later . . . I think it's correct now.

Comment: I took a quick look and it appears to just be a bug.  The logic to handle `$` and `\n` is just incorrect and causes this behavior.  If you can file a bug https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim I can try and get this fixed in the next release

Answer (score 0):

Jared did a bunch of fixes to the Regex stuff in 1.8.0 to make it more compliant with Vim's take on Regexes. Running VsVim 1.8.0 on Visual Studio 2010 and also on 2013 I am not able to reproduce this anymore.

So it looks like your solution is to upgrade to the latest version.